# Why is USB-C full duplex?

Tags: usb, data-transfer, throughput, duplex

USB-C has 4 data lanes. Two in each direction. My question is, why is this done?

USB4, for example, is 40Gbps nominally, but only half those lanes are used if you are copying files to a disk. Use all four lanes and the throughput could be doubled to 80Gbps.

Now I understand that if you are copying files in both directions you can have 2 lanes sending 40Gbps in one direction and 2 lanes sending 40Gbps in the other simultaneously. But couldn’t the same result be achieved by sending 80 Gbps half the time (or using half the frequency) in one direction and 80 Gbps the other half?

Perhaps this causes some additional overhead that really slows things down, but I’m just not sure, especially if splitting the transmission in the frequency domain.

It just seems like half-duplex would be “the best of both worlds”, by allowing 80Gbps, unless you happen to be transferring in both directions at the same time in which case you get your standard 40 Gbps.

Comment: `sending 80 Gbps half the time (or using half the frequency) in one direction and 80 Gbps the other half` which would result in 40Gbps for each direction ... so, you've gained nothing

Comment: @JaromandaX Correct, when transferring in both directions at the same time. But when not, you get twice the speed by using all the lanes. I’ve edited my question a little to help clarify what I’m getting at.

Comment: ahh, I see. To be honest though, the USB protocol is what it is, for better or worse. The fact is, it doesn't work the way you want it to work, and knowing why won't change anything. I tend to underthink things rather than overthink them :p

Comment: I guess I’m getting at a more fundamental question as to why implement full duplex for data at all. I understand the case for analog as you don’t want to have to wait to talk. But for data I’m kinda scratching my head, I just picked USB as an example.

Comment: "*Why is USB full duplex?*" -- The premise of your question is wrong. Before USB 3.0, USB is half-duplex. "*USB has 4 data lanes.*" -- Are you confusing wires for "*lanes*"? "*why implement full duplex*" -- You're ignoring the simplicity of a unidirectional line, and the time expense of switching the direction of a bidirectional line.

Comment: @sawdust  I was referring to USB 3.2 and USB4 over USB-C cable. I didn’t make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Successive USB specifications provide some degree of backward compatibility.  So USB4 can not suddenly change how the pins work without breaking that compatibility.
[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)

As to why it was done that way originally?  To make it simple, cheap and universal.  That is how the consortium decided to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is done for the sake of simplicity and ease of use.

Most modern high speed data interconnects in computing prefer single directional point to point links. The are preferred because you having a bidirectional link means that only one device can transmit at a time and in the event that both try to transmit then a collision will happen.

That collision has to be detected by both sides, the data held for some amount of time and then resent. That means bigger buffers and detection electronics and a complicated protocol of who should wait how long before trying to retransmit, all while data potentially piles up waiting to be sent.

At ultra high speeds that you have to "back off" and wait for a clear line for some unknown period of time can severely restrict usable bandwidth. (If you use fixed periods then collisions may be more likely rather than less.)

A single directional data link may waste data lines in the event that all the data flows in one direction, but it does away with a lot of the problems associated with half-duplex communication. You no longer have to wait before sending data because you know the line is always clear. You have a known quantity of bandwidth on the line, as collisions are no longer randomly cutting into it.

Your electronics are simpler and can be made faster because you've removed the collision detection bottleneck and buffers can be made smaller and used more efficiently.

It may be wasteful in the event that you know data is going primarily in one direction, but the flow of data to and from devices is effectively random from the perspective of the wires. You might be reading a file one moment, or sending display data the next.

On the subject of displays, they require data to be very consistently timed. A data collision on the line would result in a packet needing to be retransmitted, which in turn would require the monitor to wait longer before being able to show a new frame. A fast refresh monitor could find it impossible to operate at a consistent framerate in a half duplex system because the collisions are effectively random.

Half duplex also requires each side to switch between transmitting and receiving data, which can slow down the turnaround of data. If you were transmitting data then there is a brief period of time which the electronics needs to turn on the receiver or switch buffers. You'd say you can just leave the receiving electronics permanently on, but then you are permanently echoing back everything you send and you need some switch to tell the system to drop all that data. None of that is needed in full duplex.

Full duplex may well "waste" half the data lines, but it makes the entire system simpler, faster and more predictable.

Full duplex at least means you don't get a corrupted display while you are reading files from your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. You make great points, but was thinking a lot of the problems you mention with half duplex would go away if you split the transmission and reception in the frequency domain, instead of the time domain. That is, you use the same wire, but you use one set of frequencies to send the data and another set of frequencies to receive it, my understanding is that is how 5G telephony works under the right circumstances, but maybe this would just add too much complexity and overhead. After all, Ethernet does not work this way, I’m sure there’s a good reason.

Comment: Splitting in the frequency domain on a wire is again annoyingly complex but in a different way. It is not a great way to handle anything except where you have absolutely no choice whatsoever. Over the air you can at least use different radio units in the electronics but you absolutely have to use band-pass filters so that the TX side does not overload the RX side, which then means more complexity and added electronics. It is an order of magnitude more complex than just having a separate bit of wire so that you can transmit on one wire and receive on the other.

Comment: @timl2k Essentially using frequency domain stuff requires you to be able to sample the signal at several times (at least 2x, the nyquist rate) your peak frequency so you can pick out the signals you actually need in order to extract data. You then have to figure out how the signal in encoded, find embedded clocks and do a whole lot of complicated maths inside the electronic blobs. Instead by using pure digital signalling you can simply *use* that higher rate combined with a proper clock signal transmitted alongside, no decoding the signal is needed and you get a far higher signalling rate.

Comment: What you suggest is one of those things that *sounds* nice until you actually look at how to go about doing it. It is horribly complex compared to purely digital data lines wiggling at a fixed rate, and is only really useful for long distance links where the added complications and expected lower data rate cancel out. For local links such as USB pure digital keeps the cost down and the speeds up.